# Accessing PHP array passed through $_POST

Tags: php, arrays, post

I passed 2 arrays through $_POST and am trying to use the data in a php function. I am able to loop through each of the arrays using a `foreach` loop.

However, I need to loop through one of these arrays while accessing the other one in tandem (ie, on the first element in array1, I need to access the first element of array2)--so a nested foreach loop obviously doesn't help.

I have found that I cannot access the values by numerical index, however--except the first value of the array.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the current snippet:

```
$count = 1;
    foreach ($quantityArray as $quantity):  
        if($quantity < 1){
        ... 
        $order_to_item_idArray[$count]…..
        }
        if($quantity > 0){
        ...             
        $order_to_item_idArray[$count]…...
        }
        ...
    $count = $count + 1;
endforeach;
```

Comment: You could use a simple for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use something like this to achieve what you want:

**$a as $key => $c**

Here (as pseudo code):

```
$a = array('dsa','das','asf');
$b = array('aaa','eee','ggg');

foreach ($a as $key => $c)
{
    echo $c . " - " .$b[$key];
}
```

For your code, the line would be:

```
foreach ($quantityArray as $key => $quantity)
```

Comment: Great--thanks! Why does this work, but not accessing by index, numerically?

Comment: Well, it does work with the index, but in your code you are writing $count = 1, but it should be $count = 0 because arrays start with 0, not 1. And you should use $count++ instead of $count = $count + 1. Though I would consider using the $count way bad practice as the one in my answer is way easier and error proof.